# What happens to arrays when they are passed as arguments?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I recently painfully learned that if you pass in array to a function, it 'decays' to a pointer.

My question is then, what is the array treated as in the scope in which it was created and how does sizeof tell the difference? I thought all arrays were pointers and the square brackets moved the pointer forward and dereferenced in one go. Observe the following code:

```
[name@localhost lab03]$ cat arraysAsArguments.c
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int array[]) //Treated as pointer
{
  printf("%x", array);
  int size = sizeof array;
  int firstElement = sizeof array[0];
  printf("size: %d\n", size);
  printf("firstElement: %d\n", firstElement);
}

int main()
{
  int array[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5}; // expected size = 6*4 = 24 bytes
  printf("%x", array);
  int size = sizeof array;
  int firstElement = sizeof array[0];
  printf("size: %d\n", size);
  printf("firstElement: %d\n", firstElement);
  function(array);
}

[name@localhost lab03]$ clang arraysAsArguments.c
arraysAsArguments.c:5:12: warning: conversion specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
  printf("%x", array);
          ~^   ~~~~~
arraysAsArguments.c:15:12: warning: conversion specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
  printf("%x", array);
          ~^   ~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
[name@localhost lab03]$ ./a.out
57c84940size: 24
firstElement: 4
57c84940size: 8
firstElement: 4
```

In both main and function, array is of type int*. What is going on?!

Comment: array is of type int* — no, in main, array is of type int[]. Beware, arrays *aren't* pointers!

Comment: clang disagrees? Wait... what is the difference? I was not aware there was one!

Comment: The question you have to ask yourself here is this: How would the compiler know if a function taking an "array" as argument know that the function will always be called with a proper array? The answer is that the compiler can't know that, since you could call the function with both arrays and pointers.

Comment: clang is not disagreeing, because in this context, `array` has already decayed into a pointer.

Comment: Arrays are arrays. Pointers are pointers. An array is not a pointer. An expression that denotes an array may decay to a pointer if that is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cc-faq: 6.4](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html):

> Since arrays decay immediately into pointers, an array is never actually passed to a function. You can pretend that a function receives an array as a parameter, and illustrate it by declaring the corresponding parameter as an array:
>
> ```
> void f(char a[])
> { ... }
> ```
>
> Interpreted literally, this declaration would have no use, so the compiler turns around and pretends that you'd written a pointer declaration, since that's what the function will in fact receive:
>
> ```
> void f(char *a)
> { ... }
> ```

[c-faq:  Why doesn't sizeof properly report the size of an array when the array is a parameter to a function?](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html):

> The compiler pretends that the array parameter was declared as a pointer (that is, in the example, as `char *a;` ), and `sizeof` reports the size of the pointer.

I would suggest you to read entire section of [c-faq: 6. Arrays and Pointers](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Arrays decay to a pointer to their first element when passed as a function. This is why your `sizeof` call within your `function` is not what you expect, because it is calling `sizeof` on a pointer. Inside `function` this line

```
int size = sizeof array;
```

`array` has already decayed to a pointer and you are storing the size of a `int*` in your `size` variable.

You are still able to access elements within the array via the argument though as the notation

```
array[1];
```

is the same as

```
*(array + 1);
```

This is the same way you would access array elements if you had declared your function to accept an `int*` directly as parameter instead of an array. All that has happened is decay to a pointer - your `int array[]` in `main` is still an array.

Comment: Right, but then what is 'array' in my main function? Isn't it just a pointer to the first element as well?

Comment: @user2316667 No it is still an array, but when an array is passed to a function it decays to a pointer. Inside your function it has decayed to a pointer. Note that `sizeof` does not obey this rule as it is an operator rather than a function - that is why calling sizeof on the array yields the length of the array.

Comment: In your main function, `array` is an array `int []`.  However, once you are inside the printf function, it becomes an `int *`.  If you tried to do something like `array = &size` in your main function, you would see that array is not an `int *`, as you would not be able to assign to it.

Comment: Let me research int[] vs int*

Comment: Interesting... sizeof is computed at compile time. That explains a lot. So arrays are not pointers... gotta get my head around that.

Comment: @user2316667 Careful: `sizeof` may be computed at runtime when you use it on VLA (variable-length arrays, introduced on C99). I have written a thorough article on differences between arrays and pointers. You can read it here: http://codinghighway.com/?p=724

Answer (score 0):

As per your statement while passing array to function Arrays decays to pointer is correct.

We can say arrays are nothing but pointers only, the only difference is **"array are constant pointer's"**.

```
int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
```

so, here we can get the array elements by using pointer dereference as %d,*(arr+0);

```
printf("%d %d \n",*(arr+0),arr[0]);
```

Also, char *str = "string";
    printf("%c\n",*(str+0));

So, according to my understanding arrays and pointers are same, only the difference is **ARRAYS ARE CONSTANT POINTERS**.
i.e. we can't do arr++; to array.

```
int arr[3];
char *str;
```

If we are passing array to function, whatever changes we make in arr will reflect in calling function array as arr, &arr and &arr[0] are same.
Where in pointer : str and &str are different.